# How to return copy of a list where list[i] is modified in Python?

Tags: python, list

For example, I want to get copy of the list where `list[0] = 100`.

```
l = [9, 2, 5]
#I want to get [100, 2, 5]
```

I wrote this code, but it doesn't work(an error occured).

```
l = [9, 2, 5]
output = (lambda x: x[0]=100)(mylist[:])
#I want to get [100, 2, 5]
```

Any Pythonic way please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

How about simply

```
output = [100] + l[1:]
```

This can be generalised for any index `i` like so:

```
output = l[:i] + [100] + l[i+1:]
```

Comment: This does not work for the specified example, as when the list is sliced it returns integers as it is only 3 items long- and Python won't let you add together a list and an integer. Even explicitly declaring the slices as lists gets `'int' object is not iterable`.

Comment: @AlexThornton: I am not sure what you mean. The code certainly does work for `l = [9, 2, 5]` (I have tested it).

Comment: My mistake, I made the noob error of missing the colon after the `1` in `l[i+1:]`. :)

Answer (score 5):

```
copy_list = l[:]
copy_list[0] = 100
print copy_list    #  [100, 2, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question fully, what you need is a function kind of like this:

```
def modifylist(original, index, value):
    return original[:i] + [value] + original[i+1:]
```

**Example (from question):**

```
l = [9, 2, 5]
output = modifylist(l, 0, 100)
print(output)
```

*Outputs...*

```
>>> [100, 2, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
L = [9, 2, 5]
output = [100 if i == 0 else x for i, x in enumerate(L)]
```